# React App - Issues Calling 3rd Party API on First Try

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that lets a user choose from LIs to get search results from a 3rd party API based on which LI they choose. The LI has a click handler that, as part of it, makes an API request to the 3rd party. The first time they click the LI, the value is null, even though it should be a piece of the React state. This is part of the click handler function:

```
let choice = event.currentTarget.innerText;
this.setState({inputVal: choice});
let urlquery = this.state.inputVal
console.log(urlquery);
```

The first time that LI is clicked, the console.log returns null. The second time you click it, you get back the correct value. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is a LI? Where is the API call?

Comment: LI - List item. I want to figure out why the console logs are showing null on the first click, and the correct answer on the second click. Why it's taking an additional click is my issue

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

The state has not been updated when your `let urlquery = this.state.inputVal` line is run. Calls to `setState(...)` are asynchronous. Reference the react docs regarding `setState(...)` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Your options to deal with this are to use the second parameter of `setState(...)`, which is a callback which runs after `setState` has actually updated the `state`, or using `componentDidUpdate`. Both are mentioned in the docs referenced above.